Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string '1inch swap failed'
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string '1inch swap failed'this error came when I run 1inch swap functions. swap code as below
       IAggregationRouterV6.SwapDescription memory desc = IAggregationRouterV6.SwapDescription({
           srcToken: wbtcAddress,
           dstToken: usdcAddress,
           srcReceiver: payable(address(this)),
           dstReceiver: payable(address(this)),
           amount: amountIn,
           minReturnAmount: 1,  // Adjust this if needed
           flags: 0
       });

       console.log("Starting 1inch swap with V6:");
       console.log("WBTC Amount: %s", amountIn);
       console.log("WBTC Address: %s", wbtcAddress);
       console.log("USDC Address: %s", usdcAddress);

       try aggregationRouterV6.swap(address(this), desc, "") returns (uint256 returnAmount, uint256) {
           console.log("1inch swap successful, %s USDC received", returnAmount);
           return returnAmount;  // Return USDC received
       } catch (bytes memory reason) {
           console.log("1inch swap failed, reason: %s", reason.length > 0 ? string(reason) : "no reason provided");
           revert("1inch swap failed");
       }
   }

I am using 1inch aggregation router v6
